# Search Live Templates in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I'm currently using Alfred from my system-wide snippets. A lovely feature is that I can write: `snip foobar`, then it searches amongst my snippets for `foobar`.

Are there a functionality like it in PhpStorm? Or a plugin that does it? 
... I'm afraid of setting up too many snippets in there, in case that I wont be able to find them and/or forget what the abbreviation is.

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + F ?

Comment: When you press a shortcut for `Code | Insert Live Template...` it will list all applicable templates and show their description. That's the best what can be used for Live Templates .. as there is no search in template body functionality. Even the Speed search functionality (just start typing in any list/tree/popup) will only search through template description and not body (AFAIK of course).

Comment: If you need searching in actual template body, use search functionality of your File Manager/text editor and search in config files where those Live Templates are stored (only custom ones, not bundled ones or provided by plugins). E.g. on Windows that would typically be in `C:\Users\USERNAME\.PhpStorm2019.3\config\templates` folder, for other OS see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs